# Tableau running total without using Table calculation

Tags: formula, tableau-api, cumulative-sum

did anyone know what is the formula for calculation field to count running total for the group of few dimensions and sort by payment date? eg: I want to count running total for "Sales", group by ProductName, Location, Date, PPID, sort by payment date in descending order.

I can done this in "Table Calculation" but not meet my requirement. because after I get the output, I need to apply it in another calculation fields. So I need to count the running total by formula.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tableau calcs are the only calculations in Tableau that take the order of rows into account.

Your other option is to use custom SQL to write a windowing or analytic query. Read about the SQL keywords PARTITION and OVER. Not all databases support them, but most major ones do.